# Is it possible to setup a php app in one server and apache in another server?

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to setup an application server which runs PHP apps and setup a web server e.g. Apache http on another server?

Meaning, I may setup one Apache HTTPD server, and setup multiple PHP application servers, it may help to reduce the workload of HTTPD server.

Comment: It's possible, but you do normally need some way of triggering execution of code on the app servers from the web server.... you can achieve that through an API (REST or SOAP) or a queueing system

Comment: You could make your apache server also a reverse proxy server.

Comment: It's fairly common practise with larger applications

Comment: @MarkBaker, thanks for your suggestion, what you suggested here is split the functions into web services to solve the problem, but it is not my intention.

Comment: Then perhaps you should explain what it is that you envisage: what is the role of the webserver in what you're trying to do, and what is the role of the app server?

Comment: the possible situation would be, one web server (or with load balancing web servers) in front to receive incoming requests, then based on the domain name/request/IP/etc to decide which app servers to call, if incoming domain is a, then redirect to app server a to process, if incoming request is b, then redirect to app server b to process, but all requests are standard http request (for rendering html), not REST/SOAP request. hope it  clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a reverse proxy on Nginx *and at the same time it acts as a load balancer* while maintaining to use Apache with mod_php to process PHP apps.

Comment: Nginx isn't necessary you can also do it with apache self.

Comment: Dann, and xxxx (can't understand and read the chars in your name), thanks for your suggestion, any suggested reading about setting up reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called load balancing. There are several methods available to load balance the requests to different servers.

See for example this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085599/how-to-load-balance-a-php-application)

Comment: not for load balancing. my intention is to split app server (with php) and web server. my understanding of load balancing is , there is one central server to control the load and distribute the requests to a least utilised servers in cluster. so these servers in cluster are logically same.
in my scenario, the web server can have load balancing, and app server can have load balancing also. but I believe what you said here is able to solve the problem in practical way, just concept is not really right.

Comment: Well what tasks has the web server to do in your scenario? It hands off the request to the app server after it has detected that it's an PHP request. This is what the FastCGI handlers do. If you're not using PHP as an Apache module then the PHP request is not handled by the web server. So technically speaking the web server just waits for the results. It's probably possible to implement FastCGI with the handler sitting on on a remote server.

Comment: In production the following is a common way of setting web / app clusters up. Upfront is a load balancer which balances the PHP requests. All images / js / css are hosted on another server. So what happens when a client requests a page is, that the php cluster works on your request, sends back the response and all media data is fetched  from that second server. And there we have you seperation of concerns.

Comment: basically, I am thinking in this way, the architecture would be, a web server in front, there are many app servers behind it. only, web server exposure to internet. in the web server, I setup many virtual hosts, each host may map to one domain name. for app servers, one server works for one app only, different app servers have different apps. so I use this web server to distribute requests based on domain name to different app  servers.

Comment: If you route all traffic for all of your apps through this one server (which acts as an proxy in your scenario) this one server will be very busy. Perhaps up to the point, that your app servers are idle because the proxy server is out of resources and requests get thrashed at the proxy. 

I'm not sure about Apache or Nginx, but in IIS both scenarios (yours and mine) are handled by the same tool called Application Request Routing. It can act as a rule based proxy (your scenario) or as a dynamic load balance (mine). 

So back to your initial question: Sure :-)

Comment: yes, it is some kind of proxy. I use Apache, not sure how to do it. I believe the workload of the web server would not be so heavy, the workload could be less than a router.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below reverse proxy setting based on suggestion from @ルーパーヘイズ

in **web server**, setup a Apache httpd, php is not requred, in httpd.conf file add this

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
    ServerName www.internet.com
    ProxyPass        / http://www.intranet.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.intranet.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

in **app server**, setup Apache httpd and php, the conf is as per normal.

all traffic to www.internet.com will be redirect to www.intranet.com, the user only can see www.internet.com. it serves my purpose.

read some doc, it could be used for load balancing. will figure it out.